# Why failing to get notifications of Stackexchange app in Notification Bar of Andoid 6.0?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, notification-bar, usability

I receive no notifications of Stackexchange -app in Android 6.0 and/or CyanogenMod 13 in Notification Bar. 
Confirmed that the bug is existing also in Android 6.0 [MarkCh]. 
Characteristics

- not phone dependent because I can reproduce the problem in two CM13 in two different phones
- OS independent, since occurs in stock Android 6.0 and CM13
- likely Stackexchange -app specific
- not internet gadget specific (Pebble, Xiaomi Mi Band 2)

Fig. 1 Stackexchange app in App Notifications, Fig. 2 Notification Access view without *Stackexchange* app, since I cannot install it

[image]
[image]

I contacted the developer of the application by email. I also voted with one-star the application to raise awareness about the problem, which has been now more than one year in the application with Android 6.0.

Phone: Oneplus 2, Samsung Galaxy S4 gt-i9506
OS: Android 6.0, Cyanogenmod 13 official nightly, CM13 Temasek's Rom

Comment: Here's a *guess* since your version of CM is buggy as seen from many questions - perhaps notification generated by app is not shown for whatever reason. With Macrodroid, use *Trigger:* notification received, choose this app, any text ; *Action:* Vibrate Enable Vibrate on, display notification- notification from this app, text to give you a warning that you have missed a notification from this app. This may help you in two ways 1. Identify of it is a ROM problem, if so report to dev //

Comment: 2. As a crude workaround to know that you have missed a notification from this app , so that you check the app to see what is the notification

Comment: I don't believe you are the only one. I don't get stack exchange notifications on 6.0 stock.

Comment: I, as well, experienced this problem. CM13 official.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue is specific to SE Android app which is more suitable on Meta.SE (although, the development for mobile apps have been halted since long time ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug of the application with some hardware in Android 6. Update OS to Android 7 or 8 which are better supported.